# MYSQL: echo out results from table but don't echo out duplicate results?

Tags: php, mysql

I am really struggling with this so hope someone can help. I have a table like so:

```
id | msg_id | to_user_id | from_user_id | subject | content
1      1          6             10          hi       hello
2      1          6             10          hi       hello
3      1          10            6           hi       hello
4      2          4             1           hi
5      3          1             4           hi
```

i am wanting to echo out the results of this table with the below query using mysql.
At the moment i am getting all the results echoed out fine, but i do not want to echo out duplicate results. In this instance the number '1' appears in the column 'msg_id' four times. I want to use DISTINCT COUNT or something similar to select all the rows from 'msg_id' but to not echo out the duplicates and only count '1' once.

here's my mysql statement:

```
function get_inbox2() {
                global $connection;
                global $_SESSION;
                $query = "SELECT *
                            FROM ptb_messages m, ptb_profiles p
                            WHERE m.to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                            AND m.to_user_deleted !='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
                            AND m.from_user_deleted !='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
                            AND m.from_user_id != '0'
                            AND p.user_id = m.from_user_id
                            ORDER BY m.date_sent DESC";


                            $inbox_set2 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
                confirm_query($inbox_set2);
                return $inbox_set2;
            }
```

I have tried something like this but it's not showing the results:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT msg_id) totalCOUNT FROM ptb_messages WHERE to_user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
```

Comment: @Nic: a space for what? It's a correct statement

Comment: @Nic. That was just an alias. he can and should have it without spaces.

Comment: oops, you're right, my bad... i deleted the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting only the msg_id with MAX(id) (you can either get the MIN with the same logic) for each id:

```sql
SELECT m.*,p.*
FROM ptb_messages m
INNER JOIN ptb_profiles p ON p.user_id = m.from_user_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(id) AS id,msg_id 
  FROM messages 
  GROUP BY msg_id
) a ON a.id = m.id
WHERE m.to_user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']."
  AND m.to_user_deleted != '".$_SESSION[' user_id ']."'
  AND m.from_user_deleted != '".$_SESSION[' user_id ']."'
  AND m.from_user_id != '0'
ORDER BY m.date_sent DESC
```

Comment: Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p.user_id = m.from_user_id INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id),msg_id FROM messages' at line 3

Comment: ok its kind of working except its only showing 1 result but instead it should be showing 2 results. as in the 'msg_id' field there is '1' and there is '3' it's missing out the other result '3'

Comment: ok here was the solution, sorted it, thanks

    $query = "SELECT m.*,p.*
    FROM ptb_messages m
    INNER JOIN ptb_profiles p ON p.user_id = m.from_user_id
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(id) AS id,msg_id 
      FROM ptb_messages 
      GROUP BY from_user_id
    ) a ON a.id = m.id
    WHERE m.to_user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']."
    
    ORDER BY m.date_sent DESC";